# Looking for suggestions, Pi synthesizer or autonomous recorder?

Tags: audio

I'm hoping someone may help provide me some direction for a project I am working on. What I am looking to do is set up Pi to record audio (spoken) and then play back automatically. Ideally this audio could be layered with previously recorded audio, slowing building up during a recording session.

So my first question is, is it possible to continuously layer recorded sounds with a Pi?
And number two is, what would this be called (I think maybe a synthesizer, but I want the Pi to do the mixing automatically)?
And lastly, is there already a common project out there that I could look for?

Thanks, I appreciate everyone's time.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at Zynthian (Open Synth Platform). It based on Raspberry Pi (Raspbian) and provides wide range of tools:

- Real-time audio processing, low latency & jitter
- Multi-engine / Multitimbral / Multi-layer
- Up to 16 independent Synth/FX chains
- Step Sequencer, Arpeggiator, Chorder
- Recorder/Player for Audio & MIDI
- Advanced Audio & MIDI routing
- and much more ...

https://zynthian.org/technical-specifications

It may look too complex for your needs but you can get some ideas from their wiki.